# R data table issue

Tags: r

I'm having trouble working with a data table in R. This is probably something really simple but I can't find the solution anywhere.

Here is what I have:
Let's say t is the data table

```
colNames <- names(t)
for (col in colNames) {
    print (t$col)
}
```

When I do this, it prints NULL. However, if I do it manually, it works fine -- say a column name is "sample". If I type t$"sample" into the R prompt, it works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `t[[col]]`; `t$col` does an odd form of evaluation.

**edit**: incorporating @joran's explanation:

`t$col` tries to find an element literally named `'col'` in list `t`, not what you happen to have stored as a value in a variable named `col`.

- `$` is convenient for interactive use, because it is shorter and one can skip quotation marks (i.e. `t$foo` vs. `t[["foo"]]`. It also does *partial matching*, which is very convenient but can under unusual circumstances be dangerous or confusing: i.e. if a list contains an element `foolicious`, then `t$foo` will retrieve it. For this reason it is *not* generally recommended for programming.
- `[[` can take either a literal string (`"foo"`) or a string stored in a variable (`col`), and does not do partial matching.  It is generally recommended for programming (although there's no harm in using it interactively).

Comment: Can you (or someone else) clarify the cause?  I noticed something similar to NSP's question in my own work, and have found myself migrating to the solution you gave, but only because I encountered fewer issues.  I have no idea why this difference occurs.

Comment: @Iterator - `t$col` tries to find something *literally named 'col'* in `t`, not what you happen to have stored as a value in a variable named `col`. If `t` is a data frame and has no column named 'col', it will return null. As for the why, `$` and `[[` are just different tools and should be used in different circumstances; each are convenient in their own way.